# Android Menu/Sub-Menu - Menu 'Title" needs to perform NO ACTIVITY... currently refreshes webview

Tags: javascript, android, xml, menu, action

I am trying to use the Sub-Menu feature of the Android Action Bar, because I can't figure out the Spinner menus just yet. Basically, what I want, is to have my current webview activity open a new URL based on the menu item selected. That works just fine. The problem is, when I click the parent item name, it refreshes the current webview view. There should be NO activity, but I am not sure how to specify that. My code is below. Can someone explain how to make the parent item (which is commented in the code below) have no action? Thanks

```
<item android:id="@+id/apps" android:title="Action" android:showAsAction="always"> //THIS IS SUPPOSED TO BE A DROP-DOWN MENU'S TITLE, AND SHOULD NOT PERFORM ANY ACTION, CURRENTLY REFRESHES CURRENT WEBVIEW VIEW.
<menu>
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Item 1"></item> //OPENS WEBVIEW URL
<item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Item 2"></item> //OPENS WEBVIEW URL
<item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Item 3"></item> //OPENS WEBVIEW URL
<item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Item 4"></item> //OPENS WEBVIEW URL
</menu>
</item>
```

This is the code that is executed when one of the menu items is clicked:

```
//NOTE THAT THERE IS NO CASE DECLARATION FOR - R.id.apps - maybe I need one?
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url1.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url2.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url3.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.item4:
            webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url4.com");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright after hunting forever, I finally figured out the answer to this question.

As a brief explanation of what my problem was, I created a menu, with 4 items. 2 of those items contained sub-menus. The parent items of those sub-menus, when clicked, refreshed my current webview, which was a problem. I wanted those parent items to do nothing when tapped (only open the sub-menu). This is the fix:

```
//NOTE THAT THERE IS NO CASE DECLARATION FOR - R.id.apps - maybe I need one? -- ANSWER IS YES
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    // ADDING CASE DECLARATION FOR R.id.apps //
    case R.id.apps:
    { }
    return true;
    // END ADDING DECLARATION FOR R.id.apps //
    // NOTE: For a menu item that you wish to perform no action when selected, 
    case R.id.item1:
        webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url1.com");
        return true;
    case R.id.item2:
        webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url2.com");
        return true;
    case R.id.item3:
        webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url3.com");
        return true;
    case R.id.item4:
        webview.loadUrl ("http://www.url4.com");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```